# How override default styles for a select element multiple

Tags: html, css

For a select element multiple I want to remove the background color of the selected option as I'm indicating the selection with the box before each option.
The intention is give a checkbox style to a select multiple element.

Why using a select multiple? 
I'm working in a Angular App and should be useful style a select multiple as a collection of checkboxes. Doing that I will be able to use angular validations, ng-options, etc. I can build the same interface with inputs type checkbox but that imply a lot more of code for the same piece of functionality.

```css
.form-group{
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}
select[multiple]{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
   border: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: none;
}
select[multiple].form-control{
  padding: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}

select[multiple] option{
  padding: 5px 0 7px 0;
}

select[multiple]:focus{
  box-shadow: none;
}

select[multiple]:focus option:checked{
  background-color: white;
}

select[multiple] option:before, 
select[multiple] option:after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
select[multiple]:focus option:checked:before{
  background: white;
}
select[multiple] option:checked:before{
  background-color: #319DB5;
  border-color: #2c8ca1;
}
select[multiple] option:checked:after{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="someOptions">Select multiple</label>
      <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size="10" name="options" required="required" id="someOptions">
        <option label="Option 1" value="number:1">Option 1</option>
        <option label="Option 2" value="number:2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way... the easiest thing to do if you absolutely need this is to use a dropdown-menu type thing and use JS to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
select[multiple] option:checked { background: none; }
```

Comment: It seems to be an internal browser style. I've tried getting more specific by giving the select and options Ids and it still won't overwrite....

Comment: I've got it overwriting background color with: https://jsfiddle.net/r0958y30/ can't get it to leave the font color as black though.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I ended rendering it as a collection of checkboxes. Looks like the browsers don't supports such of customisation. The trade-off was make custom validations on change.

Comment: @LukeBecker Managed to change color with `-webkit-text-fill-color: yellow`, seems to be well supported https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color :)