# How to change the font color of the active item in a select multiple element?

Tags: html, css

I have a select element with the multiple attribute, like so:

```
<select name="" id="selectGroup" multiple>
    ...
</select>
```

I've styled both the hover and the selected color like so:

```
#selectGroup option:hover {
    background: lightblue;
}

#selectGroup option:checked {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px lightblue inset;
}
```

Now, the problem is is when you actually click on an item (and make it active) the font color changes to white. I've tried using the various pseudo-selectors like :active, :focus, etc. and even just putting `color` into the style for the option or just the select, but nothing ever works.

Is it possible to change the color of the active item?

See this codepen for an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywMQzp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an answer in this css rule.
You cannot override the default styles of most of form inputs, and one of the most used workaround is to transform these elements in more easy to style ones (like `div`).

```
select:-internal-list-box option:checked {
  background-color: -internal-inactive-list-box-selection !important;
  color: -internal-inactive-list-box-selection-text !important;
}
```

More infos here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms

You can also see this thread: [How override default styles for a select element multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639079/how-override-default-styles-for-a-select-element-multiple)

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Thanks.